# Eclipse: add import to a bunch of classes

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have 60 or so Java classes in an Eclipse project that I am reorganizing (everything was in the default package, ick!) that need to import another package in the project (newly created by other refactoring).

I would rather not do a `Ctrl+Shift+O` on every file. Is there someway I can speed this up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select the project in the package tree, and hit Ctrl-Shift-O. It will organize the imports for all the files of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Righclick on the source folder -> Source -> Organize Imports.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on your project and press Ctrl-Shift-O.

Or rightclick your project -> select "Source" -> Organize Imports

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl-Shift-O` shortcut is helpful to organise the import statements.

You have many shortcuts in eclipse IDE-

`Ctrl-Shift-l` will show the shortcuts in eclipse