# Eclipse: add a package to a bunch of classes

Tags: java, eclipse, packaging

Sorta like this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134711/eclipse-add-import-to-a-bunch-of-classes) (But using the solution supplied didn't exactly fix my issue)

I'm trying to rearrange a project that had all of its classes in the default package, but I don't want to go through refactoring every class there's about 450+

So how can I use eclipse to automatically put every class in a different package and automatically update the declared package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just create your new package, select all the files you want to move and drag them to their new package. It should do the automatic refactor.

Comment: There were some folders that messed with it, but after fiddling with it, and using CTRL + SHIFT + O

 I got it all to work

Answer (score 0):

I believe you right click the package -> refactor -> rename

Comment: Actually I attempted moving it to a package, then refactoring that package. Didn't really work out.

Comment: i was going to say go to where your workspace was saved and physicaly change the name of the folder but that would just give you an error in every class

Comment: not that it matters but what were you making that had over 450 classes

Comment: I didn't make it, but it's for a client for an online RSPS.